# Continuity from kernel to integral

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}), (Y, \mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces which are standard Borel.

Suppose $f:Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrabel and (upper semi-)continuous and $\kappa(\cdot \mid \cdot) : \mathcal{B} \times X \to [0,1]$ is a *continuous* probability kernel.

First question is what this means, but my guess would be that $x \mapsto \kappa(B \mid x)$ is continuous 
for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

**Q**: Is $x \mapsto \int f(y) \kappa(\mathrm{d}y \mid x)$ is (upper semi-)continuous?

I am looking for a proof or counterexample. You may forget the (upper semi-) part if that confuses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a reference to a proof of the fully continuous case in this [book](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/soc.html)
proposition 7.30.